# Forgot Windows user password

Tags: password-recovery

Forgot my User password  of windows 10 . Help me find a solution

[image: forgot password screen]

Comment: MS or local account?

Comment: User Account , what i use to log in after power on .

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution now,
 If you are logged in into your computer(via pin) but could not remember your password , Run COMMAND  as an ADMINISTRATOR. Then type "net user". and hit enter . the information of your accounts will appear . now type " net user name pass"
**write these commands without inverted comma.

name= your user name

pass= new pass .